# SQL Table CUstomized Creation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a query for the below format

```
 Country    Asset   Stock
 ------------------------
 INDIA       110      20
 USA         230      27
 CHINA       210      10
 GERMAY      120      18
```

Only the numbers are coming from database and below is the count part of number. And count queries are different for countries & I want to use country name and title as manually as given below and count should come from the query. (Not sure below is the right query)

```
'INDIA' as [country],
count(CounttblAssets.AssetID) as [asset],Count(tblAssets.AssetID) as [stock]
```

Query for counting

```
 Count(tblAssets.AssetID)
 From tblAssets
 Inner Join tsysOS On tsysOS.OScode = tblAssets.OScode
 Inner Join tblAssetCustom On tblAssets.AssetID = tblAssetCustom.AssetID
 Inner Join tsysAssetTypes On tsysAssetTypes.AssetType = tblAssets.Assettype
 Where tblAssetCustom.State = 1 And tblAssetCustom.Customvr = 'INDIA'
```

Note :  I do not have write permission from front-end application to create temp table. I can only query the data available.

Please help on this

Comment: First of all, please tag correct database name. Secondly, plesae use [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com) to create all the tables and some sample data and your output based on that.

Comment: So are you using MySql, Sql Server or Oracle database?

Comment: I am using sql server

Comment: Hi Utsav - Database is already taged in the front-end application and i do not want to craete table... Just want a table view throgh query as i mentioned in my question

Comment: Apparently aggregation should be used for your query. You need to provide the table schema for a complete answer.

Comment: Is there any way to create a function for count part by passing country value to where clause???

Answer (score 0):

```
select tblAssetCustom.Custom18 as [country],
count(CounttblAssets.AssetID) as [asset]
,Count(tblAssets.AssetID) as [stock]
 --Count(tblAssets.AssetID)
 From tblAssets
 Inner Join tsysOS On tsysOS.OScode = tblAssets.OScode
 Inner Join tblAssetCustom On tblAssets.AssetID = tblAssetCustom.AssetID
 Inner Join tsysAssetTypes On tsysAssetTypes.AssetType = tblAssets.Assettype
 Where tblAssetCustom.State = 1 And tblAssetCustom.Custom18 in (
                                                                      'INDIA'    --110      20
                                                                    , 'USA'         --230      27
                                                                    , 'CHINA'    --210      10
                                                                    , 'GERMAY'      --120      18
                                                                )
group by tblAssetCustom.Custom18
```

I'm not sure where your restrictions are. It seems that tblAssetCustom.Customer has the country strings you need. So if you want to filter countries, you must select statement and use group by.
also recommend to use aliases for readability

```
Inner Join tsysOS On tsysOS.OScode = tblAssets.OScode
```

becomes:

```
Inner Join tsysOS OS On OS.OScode = A.OScode
```

Also if you can do your own query but country isn't on a table create a derived table and join to

```
select 'BLAHBLAHBLAH', count(blah)
from tblAssetCustom ac join (select 'INDIA' as Country, 1 as AssetId UNION ALL Select 'USA', 2) as MyList
on ac.AssetId = MyList.AssetId
```

Comment: Thank you, will try this